# async.parallel in a loop throwing unhandled promise rejection

Tags: node.js, mongoose, callback, promise, async.js

I am performing several findOne() queries to a mongoDB while inside a cursor for 1 large mongoDB collection (~500MG).

I am doing:

```
var batchSize = 100;
var cursor = Col1.find().lean().cursor({batchSize: batchSize});
cursor.on('data', function (result) {
    var parm1 = result.parm1;
    var parm2 = result.parm2;
    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            Coll3.findOne({a: parm1}).then(Col3Res=>{
               callback(null,Col3Res);
            });
        },
        function(callback){
            Coll2.findOne({a: parm2}).then(Col2Res=>{
               callback(null,Col2Res);
            });
        }
    ], function(err,results){

    });
});
```

I am also getting the following error on the async.parallel for every callback() call:

> (node:127588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 125): Error: Callback was already called.

Comment: By the way, according to the described logic you are most likely triggering an error execution. First argument in the async.waterfall `callback()` is an error. Your data should be passed as a second argument, e.g. `callback(null, Col2Res);`

Comment: I am doing that in my code. There is no execution error. I'll update

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: By the way is there a reason that you are using a batchsize of 100 instead of the default of 1000?

Comment: @kentor node version v6.11.4. there is no reason for the batchsize.

Comment: the reason for `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is because you do not have any rejection handling for the promises returned by `findOne` ... also, `promises` and `async.js` rarely behave well when used together

Comment: @Jaromanda X what would ir like such a rejected handling? Can you make up an answer i can try and accept?

Comment: no, I can't make up an answer, as I don't really know how to fix code that uses async.js and promises together - my comment was regarding the warning you are getting, nothing else

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah but your comment led me to fixing it.. I changed the findOne to not use promises. Instead I am now doing col1.findOne({parm1:parm1}, function(err, result) { callback(err, result);}); which does not blow up :)

Comment: On a side note, you may also want to take a look at `parallelLimit`. Rejections could be due to a number of concurrent connections.